# Decoding/Encoding a struct with protocol type properties

Tags: swift, encoding, protocols, decode, codable

I am trying to save a configuration data structure with `UserDefaults`, thus the data structure needs to conform to the `Codable` protocol. This is my data structure:

```
// Data structure which saves two objects, which conform to the Connection protocol
struct Configuration {
    var from: Connection
    var to: Connection
}

protocol Connection: Codable {
    var path: String { get set }
}


// Two implementations of the Connection protocol
struct SFTPConnection: Connection, Codable {
    var path: String
    var user: String
    var sshKey: String
}

struct FTPConnection: Connection, Codable {
    var path: String
    var user: String
    var password: String
}
```

If I just add `Codable` to `Configuration`, it won't work. So I have to implement it myself.

```
extension Configuration: Codable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case from, to
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        let from = try container.decode(Connection.self, forKey: .from)
        let to = try container.decode(Connection.self, forKey: .to)

        self.from = from
        self.to = to
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(from, forKey: .from)
        try container.encode(to, forKey: .to)
    }
}
```

For every call on `decode()` or `encode()` I get the error `Protocol type 'Connection' cannot conform to 'Decodable/Encodable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols`.

I can see that it is difficult for the compiler to identify, which class should be used to decode the given object. But I figured it should be easy to encode an object, since every object of type `Connection` implements the `encode()` method.

I know, that the problem lies with the protocol and that the protocol can't be used with `Decodable/Encodable`. How would I change the code in `decode/encode`, so that I can still use the protocol with the various implementations? My guess is to somehow tell `decode/encode` which implementation of the protocol to use. I would appreciate any elegant solutions for this problem!

Comment: The error is right: `Codable` requires concrete classes conforming to `Codable`. There is no workaround except generics, which in practice provides a concrete type when the code is executed.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain the idea with generics in more detail?

Comment: See Jeremy's answer. That's exactly what I mean

Comment: I assume there is a typo in the question: the protocol is defined as `Connection` but, in the extension, it is referred to as `ConnectionConfiguration`

Comment: Thanks, that happens when I try to simplify my code for a question ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a limitation of Swift that a protocol cannot conform to itself. Thus `from` and `to` do not conform to `Codable` as bizarre as that seems.

You can get around it by using generics which basically means you declare `from` and `to` as arbitrary types that conform to `Codable`. Here's how:

```
struct Configuration<F: Connection, T: Connection>: Codable {
    var from: F
    var to: T
}


let myFrom = SFTPConnection(path: "foo", user: "me", sshKey: "hgfnjsfdjs")
let myTo = FTPConnection(path: "foo", user: "me", password: "hgfnjsfdjs")
let example = Configuration(from: myFrom, to: myTo)
```

So `F` and `T` are types that conform to `Connection`. When you instantiate `example` in the last line, the compiler infers `F` is `SFTPConnection` and `T` is `FTPConnection`.

Once I added the generic parameters, `Configuration` was able to synthesise the conformance to `Codable` without the extension.

---

To answer Sh_kahn's point about having two generic parameters, I did this to allow `from` and `to` to be connections of different types. If you always want the two connections to be of  the same type i.e. always two `SFTPConnection`s or two `FTPConnection`s you should declare the `Configuration` like this:

```
struct Configuration<C: Connection>: Codable {
    var from: C
    var to: C
}
```

Comment: there is no difference between that and making them properties also you repeat the same  `<F: Connection, T: Connection>` it could be 1

Comment: @Sh_Khan Making what properties? I used two generic parameters so that the `from` property could be of a different type to the `to` property.

Comment: Thanks, that kind of solves the question. But what would I do I wanted to load all my `Configuration` objects from the `UserDefaults`, which could all possibly have a different type `F` and `T`?
I would call `func loadAll<F:Connection, T: Connection>() -> [String: Configuration<F, T>]? {
        return UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation() as? [String: Configuration<F, T>]
    }`
But this wouldn't work since every Configuration could have different `F` and `T`

Comment: @Codey I don't know how to solve that particular issue. By the time you get to decoding it, you're already in the object's `init` which means the `F` and `T` have already been chosen. This might be a case for using classes and inheritance. But I would suggest writing a new question for it.

Comment: @JeremyP I posted a new question for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59364986/3272409. I would appreciate if you could take a look at it. However, thanks for your answer!